# Vertical alignment problem in begin equation

Tags: tcolorbox, multicol

The length of the "red and green" and the "blue and brown" lines are not the same. When I start writing these distances change . How do i fix it?
[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{refcount}
\usepackage[margin=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{lastpage}
%\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
% 
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage/\pageref{LastPage}}
% 
\newcounter{numex}
\newcommand\equationnumberoffset{0}%
\makeatletter
\newcommand\setequationnumberoffset[1]{%
\edef\equationnumberoffset{\number\numexpr#1\relax}%
}%
\renewcommand\theequation{\@arabic{\number\numexpr\c@equation-\equationnumberoffset\relax}}%
\newcommand\MyBox[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \edef\equationnumberoffset{\number\value{equation}}%
  \renewcommand\theequation{\arabic{numex}.\@arabic{\number\numexpr\c@equation-\equationnumberoffset\relax}}%
  \stepcounter{numex}%
  \begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced,title=\textbf{Example~\thenumex)},
  attach boxed title to top left={xshift=5mm,yshift=-2.75mm},
  boxed title style={size=title,height=0.6cm,boxrule=1.7pt,valign=center,colframe=cyan!20,colback=cyan!20,boxsep=0mm,sharp corners},
  sharp corners,
  boxrule=1.7pt,
  colframe=cyan!20,
  colback=white, coltitle=black, top=5.5mm]
  #1%
  \end{tcolorbox}%
  \endgroup
}%
\makeatother
% 
\setlength{\columnsep}{1.2cm}
\setlength\columnseprule{1.3pt}
% 

\begin{document}
%
\begin{multicols*}{2}

\MyBox{%
so we have solved equation
so we have solved equation
so we have solved equation
  \begin{equation*}
  \label{eq:solveA}
  x^2-5x+6 = 0
  \end{equation*}
  \begin{equation*}
  x_1=\frac{5+\sqrt{25-4\times6}}{2} = 3
  \end{equation*}
  \begin{equation*}
  x_2=\frac{5-\sqrt{25-4\times6}}{2} =2
  \end{equation*}
  \par
  \begingroup\centering and so we have solved equation so we have solved equation so we have solved equation so we  have solved equation
  so we have solved equation
  so we have solved equation
  so we have solved equation
  so we have solved equation
  so we have solved equation
  \ref{eq:solveA}\par\endgroup
}
\vskip 15 em
\MyBox{%
  \begin{equation}
  \label{eq:solveB}
  x^2-5x+6 = 0
  \end{equation}
  \begin{equation}
  x_1=\frac{5+\sqrt{25-4\times6}}{2} = 3
  \end{equation}
  \begin{equation}
   x_2=\frac{5-\sqrt{25-4\times6}}{2} =2
  \end{equation}
  \par\centering
  \begingroup\centering and so we have solved equation so we have solved equation so we have solved equation so we have solved equation \ref{eq:solveB}\par\endgroup
}
\vfill\null
\columnbreak
\MyBox{%
  \begin{equation*}
  \label{eq:solveF}
  x^2-5x+6 = 0
  \end{equation*}
  \begin{equation*}
  x_1=\frac{5+\sqrt{25-4\times6}}{2} = 3
  \end{equation*}
  \begin{equation*}
  x_2=\frac{5-\sqrt{25-4\times6}}{2} =2
  \end{equation*}
  \par\centering
  \begingroup\centering and so we have solved equation \ref{eq:solveF}\par\endgroup
  so we have solved equation
}

\end{multicols*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: never use equation enviornments one after the other, use a multi-line environment such as `gather` (or here I would use `align*` and `&=`  to align on the =)

Comment: but also note that tex never tries to equalize the spaces you mark (bottom of one box to top of the next) it always bases it space calculations on baseline to baseline space. (falling back to `\lineskip` spacing which is usualy a fixed 1pt, only if baseline to baseline spacing (\baselineskip) can not be achieved)

Comment: I did not fully understand. Can you revise the code for me?